# "undefined reference to `QString::fromAscii_helper(char const*, int)'"

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to Qt and to C++ and I want to create a simple project. I wrote this code:

```
#include <QString>

int main()
{
  QString str = "a,,b,c";

  return 0;
}
```

And I compile it like this :

```
g++ -o LeapMouse Leapmouse.cpp -I /home/dougui/Qt/5.1.1/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I /home/dougui/Qt/5.1.1/gcc_64/include -fPIE
```

And I have this error :

```
/tmp/cc6umRmY.o: In function `QString::QString(char const*)':
Leapmouse.cpp:(.text._ZN7QStringC2EPKc[_ZN7QStringC5EPKc]+0x34): undefined reference to `QString::fromAscii_helper(char const*, int)'
/tmp/cc6umRmY.o: In function `QTypedArrayData<unsigned short>::deallocate(QArrayData*)':
Leapmouse.cpp:    (.text._ZN15QTypedArrayDataItE10deallocateEP10QArrayData[_ZN15QTypedArrayDataItE10deallocateEP10QArrayData]+0x1e): undefined reference to `QArrayData::deallocate(QArrayData*, unsigned long, unsigned long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I do `grep -ri 'fromAscii_helper' /home/dougui/Qt/5.1.1/gcc_64/include` the function is  finded as you can see here :

```
/home/dougui/Qt/5.1.1/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qstring.h:    static Data *fromAscii_helper(const char *str, int size = -1);
```

It should be included. Did I missing something? Is it possible to include Qt's library into a standard C++ project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just including the relevant headers isn't enough in C++: when linking an executable, you also need to specify the relevant libraries and possible the directories where to find the libraries. I don't know Qt but based on your compiler invocation above, I would guess that you need to add options like

```
-L/home/dougui/Qt/5.1.1/gcc_64/lib -lQtCore
```

The first option specifies where libraries can be found assuming the compiler won't look in this directory by default and the second option is the name of the library defining the symbols. How the library is really called I don't know: if the file is `libQtCore.a` or `libQtCore.so` the option `-lQtCore` adds this library for the linker to search. You may need to replace `QtCore` by another name, however.

Comment: An error line is removed. The line "undefined reference to `QArrayData::deallocate" is staying. I'm look to apply the same procedure.

Comment: @Dougui: yes, there may be multiple libraries missing. You won't need to duplicate the `-L<path>` option if the other libraries are in the same directory but you may need to add more `-l<library>` options. Note, that the libraries are processed in the order listed on the command line.

Comment: I did this `grep -ri 'deallocate' /home/dougui/Qt/5.1.1/gcc_64/include` and I found this `/home/dougui/Qt/5.1.1/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qarraydata.h:        QArrayData::deallocate(data, sizeof(T), Q_ALIGNOF(AlignmentDummy));`. This function seems to be in QtCore too. I don't find the good library to include.

Comment: @Dougui: The missing symbol is `_ZN15QTypedArrayDataItE10deallocateEP10QArrayData`. You can use `c++filt` to find what symbol that should refer to (`QTypedArrayData<unsigned short>::deallocate(QArrayData*)`). To find the matching library, you'd either look it up in the documentation for this type (seems to be `qtbase`) or you can use `nm` to find the symbols in `lib*.a` files.